# Activity class not found in manifest

Tags: android, android-intent, xamarin, android-manifest, manifest

I am new to Xamarin development. I am following some tutorials. I want to switch to another activity in case of successful login. for that matter I made the following main activity class and another Activity Class.

```
[Activity (Label = "VanPac", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    static readonly List<string> Menus = new List<string>();
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        EditText usr = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.UserName);
        EditText pwd = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.Password);
        Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.Login);

        button.Click += async (sender, e) => {

        if (usr.Text.Length > 0 && pwd.Text.Length > 0) 
        {
            string url = "http://myapi/api/android/validatecredentials?usr=" + usr.Text + "&pwd=" + pwd.Text;

            JsonValue json = await getDataFromDB(url);
            if(json == "200")
            {
                url = "http://54.149.94.176:82/api/android/menuslist";
                json = await getDataFromDB(url);
                var res = json.ToString();
                var t = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(res);
                foreach(var i in t)
                {
                    Menus.Add(i);
                }
                var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MenusList));
                intent.PutStringArrayListExtra("menus", Menus);
                StartActivity(intent);
            }

        }

    };
```

And my MenusList Activity is:

```
public class MenusList : ListActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);   
        var menu = Intent.Extras.GetStringArrayList("menus") ?? new string[0];
        this.ListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, menu);
    }
}
```

And my Manifest file is:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.PearlSol.vanpac">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" />
    <application android:label="VanPac">
    </application>
    <activity android:name="com.PearlSol.vanpac/md5f1e9043345622e87428c0748cd41530c.MenusList"></activity>
</manifest>
```

I have not added any thing in Manifest file except the activity tag for MenusList.cs, after getting the error of "Activity Class not found".

But it is continuously giving me the Activity class not found error on the **StartActivity(intent);** in MainActivity.

How can I get it done?

Regards!

Comment: added it as <activity android:name="com.PearlSol.vanpac/com.PearlSol.VanPac.Main"></activity>.. still dont work

Comment: Shouldn it be <activity android:name=".MenusList"/> ?

Comment: Also if he is really reaching the startActivity() line the problem is with menuList not mainAcitivy, or Android Studio doesnt even compile that, eclipse should be able to compile regardless of the manifest

Comment: @Nanoc, I am using xamarin.. I have removed activities from manifest and add Activity attribute on top of menusList.. stil getting [this error](http://imgur.com/34bOqiS)

Comment: Doesnt know about that activity attribute, you should have both activities in your manifest <activity android:name=".MenusList"/> <activity android:name=".MainActivity"/>

Answer (score 0):

Add this above the "public class MenusList" and remove anything you added to the manifest manually.

```
[Activity (Label = "MenusList")]
public class MenusList : ListActivity
{ ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add mainactivity in manifest file like menulist.